# Conversor de números binários

Tags: javascript

Estou criando um conversor de números inteiros para números binários utilizando JavaScript.

**Sem utilizar array e usando somente uma função matemática** que no caso eu escolhi a divisão.

Meu código está assim agora:

```
let numero = 2
    
function binario(n){
resposta = '';

   let n2 = n/2;
   if(Number.isInteger(n2)){
       resposta = resposta + '0';   
   }else{
       resposta = resposta + '1';
   }
}

binario(numero);
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar a continuar, fiquei preso!

Comment: eu preciso entender como funciona a lógica por traz da conta usando apenas divisão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inicialmente vamos ver como funciona o algoritmo:

> Conversão de decimal para binário
>
> Para realizar a conversão de decimal para binário, realiza-se a
> divisão sucessiva por 2 (base do sistema binário). O resultado da
> conversão será dado pelo último quociente (MSB) e o agrupamento dos
> restos de divisão será o número binário.
>
> Por exemplo, vamos converter o número 45 em binário:
>
> [image: Conversão entre sistemas de numeração: decimal para binário Conversão de decimal para binário]
>
> A leitura do resultado é feita do último quociente para o primeiro
> resto. Sendo assim, o resultado da conversão do número 45 para binário
> é: 101101.
> Retirado [daqui](https://www.embarcados.com.br/conversao-entre-sistemas-de-numeracao/)

Atualmente o seu código é capaz de descrobrir o primeiro algarismo do número binário.

```
let numero = 2
    
function binario(n){
resposta = '';

   let n2 = n/2;
   if(Number.isInteger(n2)){
       resposta = resposta + '0';   
   }else{
       resposta = resposta + '1';
   }
}

binario(numero);
```

Nesse caso você precisa adicionar duas coisas ao seu código: uma forma de obter o resto da divisão e um loop para ficar dividindo esse resto até que o último quociente seja 0 ou 1.

```
let numero = 1000

function binario(n){
  resposta = '';
  let quociente = n;

  //enquanto o novo quociente não atingir 1 ou 2, o algoritmo de divisão deve ser repetido
  while (quociente > 1) {   
    //let n2 = n/2; é mais interessante usar o operador de resto da divisão, já que facilita para encontrar o proximo quociente
    // 5 % 2 = 1
    let resto = quociente % 2;
    quociente  = (quociente - resto) / 2;

    if(resto == 0){
      resposta = '0' + resposta;
      //como a resolução começa de tras para frente, vamos colocando os novos     
      //algarismos sempre no começo da string, para não ter que inverter no final   
    }else{
      resposta = '1' + resposta;
    }
  }//fim while

  //ao final concatenar o ultimo valor de quociente (que pode ser 0 ou 1) 
  //no inicio da string resposta
  resposta = quociente + resposta;
  console.log('resposta:', resposta);
}

binario(numero);
```

Answer (score -1):

> Solução

```
let numero = 2
    
function binario(n){
  const resposta = parseInt(n).toString(2)

 return resposta
}


binario(numero)
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Amigão, o AP pede que se resolva através de cálculos matemáticos. Quando assim resolva segundo as restrições impostas pelo AP e faça uma observação sugerindo um ou mais métodos que julgue adequados. Também sempre é bom explicar e juntar documentação comprobatória da explicação de como funciona o algoritmo.